# Долгий PHP скрипт и 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php

Есть `PHP` скрипт, запускаемый из браузера, время выполнения - несколько часов.

Минут через 20 после запуска в браузере вылетает `500 Internal Server Error`, сам скрипт при этом продолжает работать, успешно все доделывает и не выполняется только последняя строчка (запись в лог-файл).

`max_execution_time` выставлен в `360000`.
Скрипт при этом жрет 40-50% процессора.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А где выставлен max_execution_time? Вы выставили через php.ini или через .htaccess?

Comment: o_0. Может, в таком случае лучше не надо выполнять его в браузере?

Comment: Может есть смысл каждые 19 минут отправлять браузеры какой-то HTML коммент?

Comment: @kirelagin подобные вопросы для PHP-публики редко актуальны :)

Comment: cy6erGn0m, в php.ini

Comment: Из командной строки действительно все работает как надо... Но все же интересно, почему при запуски из браузера не выполняется именно последняя строчка кода

Comment: @e5f Не забывайте голосовать/принимать ответы, если они Вам помогают.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте копнуть в сторону технологии AJAX. На страничке HTML сделать с помощью JS запрос AJAX, на сервере скрипт PHP пускай отдает какой-либо ответ. JS на HTML будет получать сам ответ и отображать его на странице HTML.

Таким образом вы на 100% будете знать, в каком состоянии находится выполнение PHP скрипта. (Ну... хотя бы будете в курсе его выполнения).

Теперь по предыдущим комментам:

> А где выставлен `max_execution_time`? Вы выставили через php.ini или через .htaccess?

Браузер имеет тайм-лимит на ожидание ответа от сервера. Так что не в этих переменных дело. Тем более, что человек говорит, что скрипт полностью выполняется.

> @kirelagin подобные вопросы для PHP-публики редко актуальны :)

Напрасно вы так думаете :) ...Я как разработчик уже сталкивался с этим и частенько сталкиваюсь и по сей день :)

> Может есть смысл каждые 19 минут отправлять браузеры какой-то HTML коммент?

В любом случае, PHP генерирует HTML контент. Если отправить код через 19 минут, не факт, что его увидят на стороне.

Мой итог таков: AJAX вам в помощь :)

P.S. Погуглите на тему ajax.js. Так же можно обойтись с помощью jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, ваш веб-сервер, на котором запущен скрипт, стоит бэкендом к другому веб-серверу. Хороший пример - nginx+apache. 500-я ошибка возникает из за того, что, когда вы делаете запрос, его начинает обрабатывать nginx, видит динамический контент, который должен обработать apache, перенаправляет запрос к нему и ждет, пока тот завершит работу, или по истечению тайм-аута, в вашем случае, - 20 мин, отдает пользователю 500-ю ошибку. В данном случае указания `max_execution_time` не помогут, т.к. они направлены к апачу, а не к nginx.

P.S. решить проблему можно:

1. запускать скрипт как cgi от имени nginx,
2. убрать тайм-аут при переброске через nginx.

P.P.S. Что касается записи в лог файл, я бы посоветовал перехватить поток ошибок скрипта и записать его в файл, скорее всего, там выявиться какая-нибудь ошибка, например, ошибка доступа к файлу.

Comment: Ужас, зачем такие сложности, которые на 99.9% не дадут никакого эффекта ? :))) ...
Вы, Саша Мамаев, индусам курсы программирования, видимо, давали ))))
*Либо у Индусов учились :)

Comment: Только вот не пойму... если человек сказал, что скрипт ! ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ !, то какое может быть "ошибка доступа к файлу"? :)Автор, читай выше... тут без аякса никуда :)

Comment: to Асисяськин
1)эти сложности - это  правильный выход в контексте данной проблемы, а то что вы пишете про аякс вот что понастоящему индийский код. Что вернет ваш аякс, если скрипт на протяжении всей работы открывает сокет и читает из него?? И насколько будет это трудозатратно переписывать?

Comment: 2) насчет доступа к файлу, тут я уже начинаю сомневаться в ващих проф способностях, если скрипт выполняется, то совершенно не факт, что он имеет доступ к файлу логов, и если скрипт работает из командной строки и пишет в файл логов, это означает только одно, что когда его запустили от данного юзера, то он имел доступ к на запись в файл. В случае когда запускают от имени веб сервера, PHP не имеет привилегий на запись в фаил и просто не может в него записать...

P.S. автор выставите правильные права на доступ к файлу логов!

Comment: Нет, стоит только Apache...

Answer (score 1):

Высылайте выполняемые действия в браузер, для этого были php функции которые позволяли досылать на ходу контент, какие именно не помню - смотрите документацию.
Попробуйте также увеличить время ожидания ответа.
Попробуйте запускать скрипт отдельным процессом, а не через web-сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, кстати, да, каждые 19 минут делать:

```
print " ";
flush();
```

и возможно, поможет.